# Can i use REGEXP_LIKE as a condition with IF in a PL/SQL block

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a function designed to traverse a tree of organisational units filtering out some based on their level in the tree structure and weather they appear on our intranet page. The input to the function is the ORG_UNIT_ID of the starting unit, a flag to show if we should care about the intranet flag and a comma separated list of levels. For instance '2,3'. I'm trying to use REGEXP_LIKE in conjunction with an ELSEIF inside a loop to run up the tree until I hit the first eligible parent unit.

T_STOP is the control variable for the loop. R_ORG_UNIT_OVER is used to query meta-data on the above unit. During the loops first pass this will be the unit above the one passed as input to the function.

The cursor definition:

```
CURSOR C_ORG_UNIT_OVER(V_ORG_UNIT_ID ORG_UNIT.ORG_UNIT_ID%TYPE) IS
  SELECT  ORUI.ORG_UNIT_ID
  ,       ORUI.ORG_LEVEL
  ,       ORUI.SHOW_ON_INTRANET
FROM    ORG_UNIT ORUI
JOIN    ORG_UNIT_PARENT OUPA ON ORUI.ORG_UNIT_ID=OUPA.ORG_UNIT_ID_PARENT
WHERE   OUPA.ORG_UNIT_ID = V_ORG_UNIT_ID;
```

The failing code segment in the loop:

```
IF R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.SHOW_ON_INTRANET = 'N' THEN
  T_ORG_UNIT_ID := R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_UNIT_ID;
ELSEIF REGEXP_LIKE (P_SKIP_LEVEL, '(^|,)' || R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_LEVEL || '($|,)') THEN
  T_ORG_UNIT_ID := R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_UNIT_ID;
ELSE
  T_STOP := 'Y';
END IF;
```

However this code always throws a PLS-00103 error on the REGEXP_LIKE symbol. Is there some sort of limitation or alternate way in which REGEXP_LIKE works when used as a condition in a PL/SQL IF/ELSEIF block as opposed to in a regular query?

Comment: That looks valid. What is the full error stack you get, and how do the line numbers in that relate to what you've shown? Have you debugged what the actual value of `R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_LEVEL` is when it errors? And which version of Oracle are you using? Some context might be useful too - the actual problem could be on an earlier line.

Comment: I tried replacing the REGEXP_LIKE with a more basic = check against the cursor variable. It works perfectly fine, but whenever i replace it a REGEXP_LIKE i get the error shown. I can attach the full error log, but given that this is a small example from a much larger use case it may not make much sense.

Comment: OK, but that works in recent versions; possibly it didn't in 9i (can't remember off-hand when it was added to PL/SQL), so are you using an old version?

Comment: So I may have messed up her. I will modify the IF statement to more accurately reflect my code. Every part works individually but as part of an IF-ELSEIF-ELSE statement it fails.

Comment: Yes, it does help if you show the code that actually produces the error *8-)

Comment: yes sorry. I thought I had tried every condition in the IF-ELSEIF-ELSE block individually and found REGEXP_LIKE to be the culprit. It turns out it may be related to an error in the structure more so than that particular ELSEIF block. Do you see any errors @Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PL/SQL uses `ELSIF`, not `ELSEIF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS00402). With your edit your code does get the error you described; with this it doesn't:

```
IF R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.SHOW_ON_INTRANET = 'N' THEN
  T_ORG_UNIT_ID := R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_UNIT_ID;
ELSIF REGEXP_LIKE (P_SKIP_LEVEL, '(^|,)' || R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_LEVEL || '($|,)') THEN
  T_ORG_UNIT_ID := R_ORG_UNIT_OVER.ORG_UNIT_ID;
ELSE
  T_STOP := 'Y';
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have been staring at this all day,  https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS394, and I still didn't notice :(

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

```
declare 
    testvar varchar2(20) := 'Kittens';
begin
    if regexp_like(testvar, '^K') then
        dbms_output.put_line(testvar || ' matches ''^K''');
    end if;
end;

Kittens matches '^K'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Include some test data and I'll try to see what's not working as expected. For example,

```
declare 
    p_skip_level number := 2;
    org_level number := 3;
begin
    if regexp_like (p_skip_level, '(^|,)' || org_level || '($|,)')
    then
        dbms_output.put_line('Matched');
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('Not matched');
    end if;
end;
```