# Can i use REGEXP_LIKE as a condition with IF in a PL/SQL block and my string i will pass as parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
if (NOT REGEXP_LIKE(l_hdr_high_amt_fare_tab(j).fare_basis,
                                      L_HIGH_FARE_FLAG)) then
                    if l_total_fare > 13000 then
                    
                      Begin
                        update tsapp_dwh_staging_tbl
                           set error_code = 'LA_QC_S10'
                         where sys_seq_no = p_sys_seq_no;
                        commit;
```

and my L_HIGH_FARE_FLAG is parameterized.
which is
`+CHARTER(*)|+GRUPO(*)|+GROUP(*)`
this is working if i hard-code this string in my code but when i pass string as parameter it wont work.

Comment: Is this helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40547587/can-i-use-regexp-like-as-a-condition-with-if-in-a-pl-sql-block

Comment: What does "won't work" mean - do you get an error, or wrong results? Have you done any debugging to make sure the parameter actually has the value you expect; and how are you passing it in? My first thought was to wonder if you were including the single quotes in the parameter value...

Comment: i didnt get any error .....it has to exclude this condition and move to else part but it goes into if part.....

Comment: SELECT '''+' || replace(a.value_text, ',', '(*)||+') || '(*)'''
          into L_EMD_FLAG
          FROM tmaac_app_parameters a
         WHERE a.key_name = 'EMD_FLAG';   in this table i have added the parameter as comma separated i.e DPRG,DATA

Comment: Please add that into to the question, as formatted text. So you do have the single quotes inside the string; do you have that when you hard code it? In other words, does it work wit `SELECT '+' || replace(a.value_text, ',', '(*)||+') || '(*)' into L_EMD_FLAG` ?

Comment: yes its works with select statement as well as if i hard code same string in ' if statement ' it will working ....it gives me problem when i pass that string as parameter

Answer (score 0):

It worked with

```
SELECT '' || replace(a.value_text, ',', '|') || ''
FROM tmaac_app_parameters a
 WHERE a.key_name = 'EMD_FLAG'
   and a.module = 'IO'
   and a.sub_module = 'EXTRACT'
   and a.function = 'PARAMETER_PRCS';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether`regexp_like` will work in an `if` condition, then yes it will:

```
declare

    function testit
        ( stringval varchar2 )
        return varchar2
    is
    begin
        if regexp_like(stringval,'^A') then
            return 'Y';
        else
            return 'N';
        end if;
    end testit;

begin
    dbms_output.put_line(testit('Abracadabra!'));
end;
/

Y

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I'm not sure how `l_high_fare_flag` and `tsapp_dwh_staging_tbl` etc are related to the question.